# Linker error (undefined symbol) switching from g++ to clang++

Tags: g++, llvm, clang++

I'm trying to switch my project from using g++ to clang++, but I am running into undefined reference errors. The command I'm running is the following:

```
clang++ -v <long list of .o files> -I$(SRC_DIR) -I$(SRC_DIR)/third_party/gemmlowp -I$(SRC_DIR)/third_party/flatbuffers/include -I$(SRC_DIR)/third_party/ruy -Isrc/third_party/kissfft -I$(SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR)/include -I$(SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR)/libc -I$(LIBC_DIR)/include -I$(LITEX_HW_DIR) -I(VEX_SRC_DIR) -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -fomit-frame-pointer -ffreestanding -Wno-error -Wsign-compare -Wdouble-promotion -Wshadow -Wunused-variable -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-function -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-format -Wswitch -Wvla -DTF_LITE_STATIC_MEMORY -DTF_LITE_USE_GLOBAL_CMATH_FUNCTIONS -DTF_LITE_USE_GLOBAL_MIN -DTF_LITE_USE_GLOBAL_MAX -DTF_LITE_DISABLE_X86_NEON -g -O3 -fno-builtin --target=riscv32 --sysroot=/opt/riscv32/riscv32-unknown-elf --gcc-toolchain=/opt/riscv32 -menable-experimental-extensions -fuse-ld=lld -std=c++11 -fstrict-aliasing -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -fmessage-length=0 -Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-aliasing -Wno-unused-parameter -L$(BUILD_DIR)/ld -L$(SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR)/include/generated -L$(SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR)/libbase -lbase -L$(SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR)/libc -lc -L$(SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR)/libc/newlib -lm -L$(SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR)/libcompiler_rt -lcompiler_rt -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-warn-mismatch -Wl,--script=$(BUILD_DIR)/ld/linker.ld -Wl,--build-id=none -Wl,-Map=software.map -o software.elf
```

When I run the above with g++ everything compiles and runs as expected, however when I run with clang++ I get:

````
>>> referenced by base.c:34 (<BUILD_DIR>/src/base.c:34)
>>>               src/base.o:(isr)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: uart_init
>>> referenced by irq.h:19 (<VEX_SRC_DIR>/irq.h:19)
>>>               src/base.o:(init_runtime)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: getpid
>>> referenced by signal.c:159 (<LIBC_DIR>/signal/signal.c:159)
>>>               libc_signal_signal.c.o:(raise) in archive <SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR>/libc/libc.a

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: kill
>>> referenced by signal.c:160 (<LIBC_DIR>/signal/signal.c:160)
>>>               libc_signal_signal.c.o:(raise) in archive <SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR>/libc/libc.a

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: stdin
>>> referenced by getchar.c:40 (<LIBC_DIR>/tinystdio/getchar.c:40)
>>>               libc_tinystdio_getchar.c.o:(getchar) in archive <SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR>/libc/libc.a
>>> referenced by getchar.c:40 (<LIBC_DIR>/tinystdio/getchar.c:40)
>>>               libc_tinystdio_getchar.c.o:(getchar) in archive <SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR>/libc/libc.a

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: stdout
>>> referenced by printf.c:42 (<LIBC_DIR>/tinystdio/printf.c:42)
>>>               libc_tinystdio_printf.c.o:(printf) in archive <SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR>/libc/libc.a
>>> referenced by printf.c:37 (<LIBC_DIR>/tinystdio/printf.c:37)
>>>               libc_tinystdio_printf.c.o:(printf) in archive <SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR>/libc/libc.a
>>> referenced by putchar.c:39 (<LIBC_DIR>/tinystdio/putchar.c:39)
>>>               libc_tinystdio_putchar.c.o:(putchar) in archive <SOC_SOFTWARE_DIR>/libc/libc.a
>>> referenced 3 more times

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __errno
>>> referenced by sys_exit.c
>>>               sys_exit.o:(_exit) in archive /opt/riscv32/riscv32-unknown-elf/lib/libgloss.a

ld.lld: error: section .eh_frame load address range overlaps with .data
>>> .eh_frame range is [0x400A29F0, 0x400A31F3]
>>> .data range is [0x400A29F0, 0x400A318F]
clang-15: error: ld command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```

Is there something that needs to be done differently when building libraries and linking with clang++ vs. g++ that I'm missing?
````

Comment: A part of the output from -v should be the (often very long) command used to invoke the linker. Look for .o/.sa files that are added by one and not the other.